# Find a matrix $B$ such that $B^2=A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, radicals

$A= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2+3i \\ 2-3i & -1 \end{pmatrix}$
What is matrix $B$ such that $B^2=A$?

Its eigenvalues are $\sqrt{14}, -\sqrt{14}$
and I tried to use formula $B=U\sqrt{\lambda}U^{H}$ where $U$ is unitary matrix.
But then $\sqrt{　}$ of $-\sqrt{14}$ is not possible.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why is $\sqrt{-\sqrt{14}}$ not possible? You are working over complex numbers.

Comment: In addition to the other answers, you can consider taking the square root of A using the algorithm here [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_2_by_2_matrix ]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\lambda^2 - 14$, so $A^2 - 14 I = 0$.
Thus $(a A + bI)^2 = (14 a^2 + b^2) I + 2 a b A$.  To make this equal to $A$, we want 
$2ab = 1$ and $14 a^2 + b^2 = 0$.  Thus $b = 1/(2a)$ and $14 a^2 = -1/(4a^2)$, or 
$a^4 = -1/56$. Take $a$ to be any of the four fourth roots of $-1/56$, and you have a solution.

Comment: I'm in the same problem, but I have a matrix  $A=\pmatrix{1&2\cr 2&4\cr}$. I don't understand what you did to find the matrix B. Could you please explain me?

Comment: Your $A$ has characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2 - 5 \lambda$, so $A^2 = 5 A $.  Thus $(a A + b I)^2 = a^2 (5A) + 2 a b A + b^2 I$.  For this to be $A$, we need $5 a^2 + 2 a b = 1$ and $b^2 = 0$.  Thus $b = 0$ and $a = \pm 1/\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: I see, you did that by applying the teorem of Cayley-Hamilton

Answer (score 5):

You can always use the "brute force" approach: let $$B=\pmatrix{r&s\cr t&u\cr}$$ calculate $B^2$, set it equal to $A$, and solve the resulting (nonlinear) system of four equations in four unknowns.

Comment: @Divine, it's probably better to post your enquiry as a new question, rather than burying it in the comments on a ten year old answer (after first searching to see whether your enquiry is a duplicate). But you could try carrying out the plan of action suggested in my answer, and seeing whether there is any obstruction to it working for matrices with complex entries.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I am learning typing of mathematical expression in mathstackexchange , Poor command on Latex stops me to ask my doubts over here.

Comment: @Mathemusica .......dnt stop yourself. Just refer this  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/246221